# Sorting an array of objects in ng-repeat using orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have an array of objects and I am trying to sort (or group) them by a boolean object attribute with using angularjs' ng-repeat functionality.

I tried using orderBy and groupBy but none of them worked.

here is my html:

```
<tbody md-body>
                        <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in dashboardCtrl.unAckAlertList | limitTo : 4 | orderBy: 'item.urgent'">
                            <td md-cell>
                                <i ng-if="item.urgent" class="fa fa-warning" style="font-size:22px;color:red;"></i><i ng-if="!item.urgent" class="fa fa-warning" style="font-size:22px;color:slategray;"></i><span><b> {{item.status}}</b></span>
                            </td>
                            <td md-cell>
                                {{item.MyName}} / {{item.sourceProperty}}
                            </td>
                            <td md-cell>
                                {{item.name}}
                            </td>
```

It never worked and I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following syntax:

```
orderBy: 'urgent'
```

Here the quote from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) on using `string` as an orderBy parameter:

> string: An Angular expression. The result of this expression is used to compare elements (for example `name` to sort by a property called `name`)...

Comment: yes, I figured this was part of the problem too but also having ng-repeat limit to 4 before sorting the array caused the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

`orderBy` looks for the properties you tell it to, within the current element from your array.

In the snippet you provided, you gave the current element the name of `item`, which is what `orderBy` will look for properties in.

You do not need to write `orderBy: item.urgent`. If you write `orderBy: urgent`, Angular should be able to figure the rest out.

Answer (score 0):

2 things caused this error:

1. Array should be sorted first and then you should limit the view.
2. Whichever object attribute you wanted to sort by, you should only put the attribute name, not object itself.

instead of:

```
ng-repeat="item in dashboardCtrl.unAckAlertList | limitTo : 4 | orderBy: 'item.urgent'"
```

it should be

```
ng-repeat="item in dashboardCtrl.unAckAlertList | orderBy: 'urgent' | limitTo : 4 "
```